# The argument type 'List<dynamic>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String?'. In firebase document

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I try to update list of userUid at the same time but it says this *The argument type 'List' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String?'*

```
              StreamBuilder(
                          stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                              .collection("groups")
                              .doc(groupId)
                              .snapshots(),
                          builder: (context,
                              AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
                            var userDocumentUid = snapshot1.data?["members"];
                            if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                              return Container();
                            }
                            return ... 
    //Elevated Button
    onPressed: () async => {
             await DataBase().deleteGroup(userDocumentUid)
    }
    //My DataBase
        Future<String> deleteGroup(String List<dynamic> userDocumentUid) async {
            String retVal = "error";
            try {
             await firestore
                  .collection("users")
                  .doc(userDocumentUid)
                  .update({'groupId': ""});
        
              retVal = "success";
            } catch (e) {
              // ignore: avoid_print
              print(e);
            }
            return retVal;
          }
```

Is there anyway to get the doc as list not as only a string?

Comment: Hi It'sPhil, I have posted the update on the answer,please check and let me know if that was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like snapshot1.data?["members"] is returning a string thus initializing the userDocumentUid a string type.
Try
`userDocumentUid[0] =  snapshot1.data?["members"];`
this will make a list

Comment: You can also use List.add() method to add an element to the list

Answer (score 0):

The error comes up when you are trying to return an argument type which is a list value with a mismatched parameter subtype.
To get the list data try below code after execution of the below code all the ids will be stored in the list ids

```
List<String> ids=[]; 
QuerySnapshot snapshot=await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('following').document(widget.currentUser.id).collection("userFollowing").getDocuments();
snapshot.documents.forEach((doc) { ids.add(doc.documentID); });
```

You may check the documentation available for more details on  [List collection](https://pub.dev/documentation/collection/latest/collection/ListEquality-class.html) and [Argument Type error](https://dart.dev/guides/language/sound-problems#the-argument-type--cant-be-assigned-to-the-parameter-type-)

**UPDATE**

```
final QuerySnapshot result = await Firestore.instance.collection('myCollection').getDocuments();
final List<DocumentSnapshot> documents = result.documents;
```

and after that you can loop through it with

```
documents.forEach((data) => print(data));
```

Comment: Sorry I am a bit new I don't understand your code can you maybe try to implement it in my code above (I've updated it)